# How to speed up data exchange between Python processes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm using Python's `multiprocessing` module for parallel processing of tasks. My goal is to have multiple processes work cooperatively on a set of tasks as efficiently as possible. To avoid duplicating work, I'm using a shared dictionary to track completed tasks. If a task is already completed by one process, other processes should skip it and pick a different task.

However, I've encountered a performance bottleneck. The process of checking the shared dictionary for completed tasks is significantly slowing down the overall execution. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import multiprocessing
import random

def worker(shared_dict):
    for i in range(1000000):
        num = random.randint(1, 100000)
        if num not in shared_dict:
            shared_dict[num] = num**2 # computationally complex task

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a manager and a shared dictionary
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    shared_dict = manager.dict()

    # List to keep track of processes
    processes = []

    # Create and start 5 processes
    for _ in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(shared_dict,))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    # Wait for all processes to complete
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print(shared_dict)
```

I used PySpy for profiling and noticed that a significant amount of time is spent in sending and receiving data from the shared dictionary (as shown in the attached profiling image).

[image]

I'm looking for suggestions to optimize this data exchange. Is there a more efficient way to manage shared data in Python multiprocessing? How can I reduce the overhead associated with accessing and modifying the shared dictionary?
I am willing to accept some duplications if it allows to dramatically increase performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing in Python along with using a manager to actually create a shared dicts, indeed can be slow, long  story short it involves inter-process communication where every access to that particular shared dictionary requires two way communication (worker processes and manager processes).

Well, the code which you shared doesn't give me at least a bit of context here, but in general, you would have several approaches when optimizing speed in these case of scenarios:

1. **By minimizing the access to Shared Objects:** It would involve reducing the frequency of reads and writes, perhaps batching these writes and reads locally in each process and then writing them less frequently.
2. **Lock-Freeing Data Structure:** Simply means using a `multiprocessing.Value` or `multiprocessing.Array` when you deal with raw shared memory, why? The reason is that it doesn't require use of manager. Also, this works pretty well with fixed-size collection of shared state.
3. **Division of the work upfront:** Instead doing checks of shared dictionary for each and single task, divide them upfront by using processes, that way you'd achieve having each process with his own subset to work through without checking shared state.
4. **Usage of queues:** Simply use a `multiprocessing.Queue`, that way you're distributing tasks to worker processes, once that's finished you can write it to results queue.
5. **Local Caching:** Each process can maintain a local set of completed tasks and synchronize with the shared dictionary at specific intervals instead of every iteration.
6. **Concurrency Control:** If you have to use Manager, then you might as well consider using `multiprocessing.Lock` - by using it you are controlling access to the shared dictionary, in order to avoid race conditions and also to ensure that you are using only one process (one process can access the shared state at a time). Btw. Be careful with this one, as it can become bottleneck if you're overusing it.
7. **AAvoid Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) Contention:** In case you're doing tasks which requires CPU to "hop in" significantly, Python's GIL can become bottleneck in such scenarios, so in that case you'd want to consider using numpy as a library for number crunching to release GIL, OR by using another programming language.

Also, I've seen people switching architectures because the nature of these scenarios were too complex - basically what it means, they started using message brokers like Redis or RabbitMQ to handle that process of communication.

**UPDATE 1:**

Example where minimizing access to shared objects, dividing work upfront and using queues is implemented:

```
import multiprocessing
import random

# Defining worker func that processes tasks
def worker(task_queue, result_queue):
    local_results = {}
    while not task_queue.empty():
        try:
            # Getting task here
            num = task_queue.get_nowait()
        except multiprocessing.queues.Empty:
            break  # No tasks?

        # Processing the task itself
        local_results[num] = num**2

    # Local results goes into local_results = {}
    result_queue.put(local_results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_workers = 5
    task_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # Filling the task queue with init. tasks
    for i in range(1000000):
        task_queue.put(random.randint(1, 100000))

    processes = []
    for _ in range(num_workers):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(task_queue, result_queue))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()


    combined_results = {}
    for _ in range(num_workers):
        combined_results.update(result_queue.get())

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    # Just a little check if combined_results dictionary is containing all results
    print(combined_results)
```

Comment: 1. local batching is a good idea.
2. I will try Array.
3. I can not fill the task queue upfront
4. How can I use a queue when I do not have tasks upfront? As I understand queue is used to exchange messages. In my case, I need some storage of reused tasks (already squared numbers)
5. Local caching is a good idea.
6. Why do I need Lock if a Dict is already synchronized?
7. I use asyncio inside Processes
8. Why Redis could be faster than Manager.Dict?

Comment: Well usage of queues and division of the work upfront kind of goes into one basket, can't work one without other, so this is falling of (As I said I didn't have enough context, this would be general approaches). Well, in your case the internal locking should suffice, usage of lock is for more complex operations that needs to be (atomic?). Usage of asyncio is okay in your case  since bottleneck origins from inter-process comm. rather than CPU-bound ops (it's less of a issue). @OlegDats

Comment: @OlegDats Redis can outperform `Manager.Dict` because: a) is written in C (ANSI C to be more precise), b) is avoiding Python's "pickling" when transmitting data between different processes, c) efficiently manages access from multiple clients. Shortly, it's designed for tasks which involves data structure server ops, which CAN be significantly faster when you compare it to the Python's `Manager`.

Comment: If I keep using Manager.Dict then `if num not in shared_dict` can be optimized by using a local copy of `shared_dict`. 
How can I make async versions of updating and making a local copy of `shared_dict`? Do I need to use Queue for this?

Comment: @OlegDats Well, if you decide to use a local copy of `shared_dict` to check is task cmopleted or not, (`num not in shared_dict`), indeed - it's optimizable. To make async updates to the `shared_dict`, you'd be probably using `asyncio` lib. along with the `asyncio.Lock`, which would ensure that updates don't interfere with each other, but keep in mind - that `asyncio` is not inherently designed to work within multiproccessing's worker processes - each worker runs its own event loop

Comment: @OlegDats And to answer a question about `Queue` itself - you don't have to use it, I mean not necessarily, unless your goal is implementation a `producer-consumer pattern`, that would mean that tasks are produced and consumed by different processes or threads, that being said, A `queue` itself is just helpful for managing tasks, not for holding the state or results of tasks itself.

Comment: One more thing mixing asyncio and multiprocessing needs careful handling in order to avoid deadlocks. @OlegDats

Comment: Array is slow. I have switched to Redis and it dramatically improved performance.

Comment: @OlegDats I am really glad that I mentioned Redis and that you switched architecture, and that it really made a huge difference.